# MATLAB: X and Y do not have the same number of observations.(error) classregtree()

Tags: matlab, classification

Im trying to use function `classregtree` for building a tree. classTrain is a cell array with 2 string values. I use `grp2idx`() function for indexing strings, not using this function causes error `"X must be a matrix of floating-point numbers."`. Now I have in training_data = 200x1 and in test_data = 1800x1 and i got this error `"X and Y do not have the same number of observations."` Training and Testing data i generate randomly.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem?

```
classTrain = {};
        classTest = {};
        for ind = trainInd  
            classTrain{end+1} = class{ind};
        end
        for ind = testInd
            classTest{end+1} = class{ind};
        end


        %1) building tree
        training_data = grp2idx(classTrain);
        test_data = grp2idx(classTest);
    >>>> t = classregtree(training_data', test_data',  'method','classification' , 'prune', 'off', 'splitmin', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the help entry says:

classregtree Create a classification and regression tree object.
    T = classregtree(X,Y) creates a decision tree T for predicting response
    Y as a function of predictors X.  X is an N-by-M matrix of predictor
    values. If Y is a vector of N response values,

e.g., X should be the training data, and Y the labels of the training data.  So if X is N by M, Y should be N x 1.

You can then RUN the tree on new data using "eval"